# Prove that the following function is $C^\infty$ in the point $\xi=0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, fourier-series

Prove that the following function is $C^\infty$ in the point $\xi=0$:

$$f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb C:\xi\mapsto {e^{i\cdot\xi\cdot λ}-1\over i\cdot\xi}-λ$$
Any way how to prove this? i think that i must use series but i do not know how

Comment: If your function is defined on $\mathbb{R}$, it has only one variable: what are $x$ and $y$?

Comment: i corrected it was my fault thanks

Comment: **Hint.** You could work out its power series, and in the process discover that it converges everywhere.

Comment: how i can use power series? i could use geometric series or something like that

Answer (score 0):

Hint. Use taylor's integral formula for $\xi \to e^{i\xi \lambda}$, then try to use some "regularity under the integral sign" theorem. Conclude by recurrence.

Comment: I don't understand the "regularity ..." bit.

Comment: differentiation under the integral sign.

Comment: Sorry, I saw Taylor and thought you meant Taylor series.

Comment: i will try it and if i stuck anywhere i am gonna ask

Comment: i tryed to use taylor form with integral remainder but i didnt coclude , maybe i can not use it correctly